# C++ Split Int Into 4 Parts (32 Bit Machine)

Tags: c++, memory, int, 32-bit

Alright so If I have an int like this (used to store a line of ASM)

```
int example = 0x38600000; //0x38600000 = li r3, 0
```

How would I split this int into 4 seperate sections? I've come up with this

```
int example = 0x38600000;
char splitINT[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    splitINT[i] = *(char*)(((int)&example + (0x01 * i)));
}
//splitINT[0] = 0x38;
//splitINT[1] = 0x60;
//splitINT[2] = 0x00;
//splitINT[3] = 0x00;
```

The above code actually works perfectly fine when reading memory from the process my executable is running within, but this does not work when trying to read the programs own memory from within itself like shown in the code example above.

So how else would I go about splitting an int into 4 separate parts?

Comment: How do you define "does not work" in this instance? What does it do differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is really confusing since I am not sure why it works at all given the cast to `int` in the statement. You can read each individual byte of the 32-bit `int` by casting it to a `char *`, where a `char` is the size of one byte on your machine.

```
int example = 0x38600000;
char *bytepointer = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&example);
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(bytepointer[i]) << " ";
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```

You can also use `bytepointer` to modify the memory contents of the `int` byte by byte.

Additionall, you should also look up the role of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) in determining the memory layout of integers. A machine can choose to use a big- or small-endian layout, and this will change the order in which the bytes are printed and how you can modify the `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Also, the cast to int simple converts the raw memory address to a 4 byte integer so I can add and subtract from the memory address of the variable without any compile errors. Assume the variable "example" is located at 0x12341234 in memory, all I'm doing in the example code snippet essentially is `*(char*)(0x12341234 + (0x01 * i))`

Comment: @Coder1337 I see now. I see how that would work. At the risk of being pedantic, I would warn you this can fail since the pointer to `int` case is implementation-defined and can caused undefined behavior if the pointer address is outside the range of `int`.

Comment: in my opinion, union is a better way to do this.  It allows you to look at the same value different ways without playing with raw pointers and recasting to coerce the pointer to other types.

Comment: @ttemple I think the `union` is a bit prettier, although you need to be comfortable with less common constructs in C++ like `union`. At the risk of sounding like a language lawyer, technically only my version is guaranteed to work across all systems (ignoring the endianness issue for a moment). Your version actually causes undefined behavior since you are only supposed to read/write on member variable of a `union` at a time, although it will do what you expect on all modern systems that I known of.

Answer (score 1):

```
union split_union
{
    int as_int;
    char as_char[4];
}

// either initialize like this...
split_union example{0x38600000};

// or assign like this...
split_union ex;
ex.as_int = 0x38600000;


//example.as_char[0] = 0x00;
//example.as_char[1] = 0x00;
//example.as_char[2] = 0x60;
//example.as_char[3] = 0x38;
// correct order for Visual Studio on x86.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned char c1 = static_cast<unsigned char>(example & 0xFF) ;
unsigned char c2 = static_cast<unsigned char>((example >> 8) & 0xFF) ;
unsigned char c3 = static_cast<unsigned char>((example >> 16) & 0xFF) ;
unsigned char c4 = static_cast<unsigned char>((example >> 24) & 0xFF) ;
```